# How to check index exists in elasticsearch by NEST 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I use C#
How to check an index already exists in Elasticseach.net
In the document of Elastic.co bản 1.x 
I see the method "TypeExists" that version 6 doesn't support

Answer (score 1):

With 6.x client, it's

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

if (client.IndexExists("index_name").Exists)
{
    // index exists, do something
}
```

Comment: Any chance you know how to check if an index exists in NEST 7.x? They removed the indexexists method

Comment: `client.Indices.Exists()`. See https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-and-elasticsearch-net-7-0-now-ga

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been scouring their API for this simple line of code! Bless you!

Comment: @Bodokh you might want to also reference NEST.7xUpgradeAssistant to allow you to steadily migrate to the new API methods: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.7xUpgradeAssistant/

Comment: if (client.Indices.Exists("your-index").Exists)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("index already Exist");

            }